# Analytic functions defined by integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I define a function using an integral:

$$f(z)=\int_{\mathbb R} g(z,x)\ dx,$$

where $g$ is some function, $z$ is a complex variable, and $x$ is a real variable. Suppose the integral exists for $z\in U$, where $U$ is some open region. What are sufficient conditions on $g$ so that $f$ is analytic here, and why do they suffice?

I looked in Ahlfors but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Ahlfors probably states and proves Morera's theorem.  That can prove analyticity of the Gamma function and the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Perhaps consult some previous questions and their answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177953/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81949/ or maybe several others

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It suffices that $g$ is analytic in $z \in U$ for each $x\in {\mathbb R}$ and $\int_{\mathbb R} |g(z,x)|\ dx$ is locally uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $U$.  For then if $\Gamma$ is any closed triangle in $U$,
Fubini's theorem  says $\oint_\Gamma f(z) \ dz = \int_{\mathbb R} \oint_\Gamma g(z,x)\ dz\; dx = 0$, and Morera's theorem says $f$ is analytic in $U$.

EDIT: I guess we'd better also assume that $g(z,x)$ is measurable.

Comment: In the long run, a person will better preserve their sanity if such questions are construed as asking when an integral of a function-valued function lies again in the same space as the integrands (and, naturally, with other reasonable compatibilities). Although I anticipate that the kind of answer I am about to give is not as "immediate" as probably desired, I do recommend it long-term: in almost all cases I know, an integral of (parametrized) vectors lies again in the same TVS when the integral can be written as a continuous, compactly-supported integral of vector-valued functions, and ...

Comment: ... invoke existence of Gelfand-Pettis (a.k.a. "weak") integrals of such functions, with values in a quasi-complete (locally convex) TVS.

Comment: When you say Fubini's theorem,you mean just the part switching the integrals. But the part where the double integral equals 0 is given by Cauchy's theorem for closed paths on convex regions, right ? In that case we should add that the $U$ region is convex as a condition.

Comment: @PerelMan It is not necessary that $U$ is convex.  The paths $\Gamma$ are triangles contained (with their interiors) in $U$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, indeed! It is then Goursat's Theorem

Comment: @RobertIsrael Could you please confirm that only local integrability over compacts of product spaces is enough to use Fubini's theorem? Because in Fubini's theorem wikipedia page, it's about full integrability:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** [Morera's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201444/find-the-region-where-an-integral-is-defined/201627#201627) should tell you something.